# Is there an ESLint rule to prevent defining React "fragments" inside of components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I know "fragments" isn't the right word since this means something else in the React ecosystem, but I can't really think of a better word. Hopefully, an example will suffice...

We have this pattern all over our codebase of defining individual bits of JSX assigning it to variables inside of a component, and then inserting them into the return statement:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const header = (
    <div>
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
    </div>
  )

  const body = (
    <div>
      <p>This is a paragraph</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Here's a list with some items</li>
        <li>Another item</li>
        <li>One more item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )

  const footer = (
    <div>
      <p>This is a footer</p>
    </div>
  )

  return (
    <>
      {header}
      {body}
      {footer}
    </>
  )
}
```

This is obviously a very simple example, but you can imagine other components being called inside of these "fragments" as well. The rerendering and state persistence issues are real, and this has caused a few bugs over time that have been very hard to figure out. I would love to refactor all instances of it.

It's not a terribly easy thing to find throughout the codebase, so I would love it if there's an ESLint rule (or another, similar way) to prevent the definition of variables containing JSX inside of a component.

Comment: I'm not aware of ay lint rule for that. And i'm not really sure what rendering and state persistence issues could result from this, as long as you're not defining new component types inside MyComponent.

Comment: You can always make your own eslint rules: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/plugins

Comment: There shouldn't be any bugs arising from this. Splitting jsx into fragments is often cleaner.

Comment: You can probably build something simple with the https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax rule, allowing JSX only inside `return` statements.

Comment: You can use <React.Fragment>, they are both the same, but is more readable.